# Why does natsort fail on this array of arrays when incorporated into a for loop?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

On one of the pages of my site I have 9 natsorts in a row on 9 different arrays, and everything works as intended:

```
natsort($Array1);
natsort($Array2);
natsort($Array3);
natsort($Array4);
natsort($Array5);
natsort($Array6);
natsort($Array7);
natsort($Array8);
natsort($Array9);
```

However, I tried to construct an array of arrays and incorporated this into a for loop as follows:

```
$MasterArray = array($Array1, $Array2, $Array3, $Array4, $Array5, $Array6, $Array7, 
$Array8, $Array9);

for ($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++) {
    natsort($MasterArray[$i]);
}
```

This failed with flying colors...why is this invalid?

Note: error_log ---> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use [] for reading in....line with $MasterArray is the issue.

Comment: In what way does it fail? Error messages? Fails to sort? (in which case, how are you checking)? Because the original `$Array1` etc won't be sorted, only `$MasterArray[0]`, etc....

Comment: `$MasterArray = array(&$Array1, &$Array2, &$Array3, &$Array4, &$Array5, &$Array6, &$Array7, &$Array8, &$Array9);` may help

Comment: Sorry about that...I edited my post. It doesn't sort and is considered a "Fatal Error" (see Note: at bottom of post)

Comment: Is the fatal error on the line with the natsort(), because this should be perfectly valid PHP

Comment: It's on the line with $MasterArray

Comment: @Mark Baker....your ampersand suggestion completely solved it...what does the & do? Can you please put this in answer form so I can mark it as the "Accepted Answer"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
MasterArray = array(&$Array1, &$Array2, &$Array3, &$Array4, &$Array5, &$Array6, &$Array7, &$Array8, &$Array9);
```

`&` is a "by reference" link to the original arrays... without the "&", your `$MasterArray = array($Array1, ...)` creates $MasterArray with **copies** of $Array1, etc, so the sort reorders the copy....

with the `&`, it creates a link to the original $Array1, etc, so the sort will reorder the original $Array1